# pdf to sharepoint

Tags: pdf, document-converter

My coworkers currently fill out a pdf file and then it is manually entered into an excel table. I am trying to automate the process by putting it in a SharePoint page. I know it is quick and easy to convert a pdf to excel. I also have found it is possible to go from excel to SharePoint. Does anyone know of a way to convert a pdf table to a SharePoint table? Or does it have to be a two part process?

Comment: How do you concert pdf table to excel in existing process? Using some 3rd party tool?

Comment: yes, and no. I haven't found one that will update an existing excel. I  manually concatenate them.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate PDF forms to SharePoint directly, using 3rd party tools like PDF Share Forms. You can find details on their homepage www.pdfshareforms.com. Our company has been using PDF Share Forms products for about a year and our HR department is really satisfied, because they are able to create forms by themselves. I am happy as well, since there is much less load on IT dept with all this form related questions....